# ConcurrentHashMap.put V.S. ConcurrentHashMap.replace

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

From the Javadoc I know `ConcurrentHashMap.replace` is atomic, but what about `ConcurrentHashMap.put`? I see they are differently implemented in the source code but I'm not able to figure out their differences. Any gurus to give some guidelines about how to use these two methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are functionally different. `replace` only stores the key-value pair if there already was a value stored under the specified key. The API documentation of `replace` explains it:

> Replaces the entry for a key only if currently mapped to some value. This is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if (map.containsKey(key)) {
>     return map.put(key, value);
> } else return null;
> ```
>
> except that the action is performed atomically.

Answer (score 2):

`put()` is inherited from class `AbstractMap` which `ConcurrentHashMap` extends. No particular concurrency contract is on `put()`. This inheritance allow the use of `ConcurrentHashMap` in a "traditional" context of a Map. But no `AbstractMap` method is atomic.

`replace()` is implemented as requested by the `ConcurrentMap` interface. This interface require atomic operations like `replace()`. Only methods of this interface are to be used in a concurrent-aware code.

To have an atomic `put()` operation, use `putIfAbsent()` coming from that same `ConcurrentMap` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of PUT in ConcurrentHashMap, the implementation has atomic behavior added to it, and Java docs say:

> Blockquote
>   This class obeys the same functional specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods corresponding to each method of Hashtable.

As I understand, it should be safe to use put method in a ConcurrentHashMap.